# Excel Chart data range increase programatically using c#

Tags: c#, excel

I'm facing problem while updating a chart in excel.

I'm inserting the row values using c# code, but now after inserting the data I want to increase the chart range so that it will fully show the graph . i have tried the below code .

Please let me know how can I resolve this.

```
xlApp = new Excel.Application();           
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("E:\\test\\DT", 0, false, 5, "", "", false,
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, 1, 0);   //@"H:\TestFile.xlsx"
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Sheets.get_Item(1);
Workbook wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)xlApp.ActiveSheet;
rng = ws.get_Range("A2", "A7");
// rng = ws.get_Range("Trend_NCM!$A$2:$AD$7",useDefault);
// rng = ws.get_Range()                   //  //ActiveChart.SetSourceData
Source = rng("Trend_NCM!$A$2:$AD$7");
Excel.ChartObject chartObject11 = (Excel.ChartObject)ws.ChartObjects("Trend NCM");
chartObject11.Activate();
```

In the 2nd image , i'm dragging the chart manually , i just want to make it by c# only for the new columns which are added each time .

[image]

Comment: What interface are you using to manipulate Excel? Office.Interop? Could you show your code in C#? Please be more specific.

Comment: Hi i'm office.interop

Comment: hello @Taosique , i need to change the set source data range using c# , pease do let me know if you hyave any idea .

Comment: @Taosique please suggest me from my macro answer to C#                                         '//Macro result '
    'ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate       ActiveChart.SetSourceDataSource:=Range("Trd_NM!$A$2:$AC$7")      ActiveChart.SetSourceDataSource:=Range("Trd_NM!$A$2:$AD$7")'

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work? (Put in the values you need below, also remember to do appropriate clean up of com objects)

```
Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook book;
Excel.Worksheet sheet;
Excel.ChartObject chartObj;
Excel.Chart chart;
Excel.Series series;

book = app.Workbooks.Open(@"Path to excel workbook");//Open the work book
sheet = book.Sheets["Sheet name"];//Select the sheet the chart is on
chartObj = sheet.ChartObjects("chart name");//Select the ChartObject
chart = chartObj.Chart; //Select the Chart from the ChartObject
series = chart.SeriesCollection(1);//Select the series you are changing
series.Values = (Excel.Range)sheet.Range["A1:A5"]; //or sheet.Range[sheet.Cells[1, 1], sheet.Cells[4, 5]] works too
```

**Edit:**
Try the below for updating the entire data source instead of a single series.

```
Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook book;
Excel.Worksheet sheet;
Excel.ChartObject chartObj;
Excel.Chart chart;

book = app.Workbooks.Open(@"Path to workbook");//Open the work book
sheet = book.Sheets["sheet name"];//Select the sheet the chart is on
chartObj = sheet.ChartObjects("Chart name");//Select the ChartObject
chart = chartObj.Chart; //Select the Chart from the ChartObject
chart.SetSourceData(sheet.Range["A1:A5"], Excel.XlRowCol.xlColumns); //I do not know whether your charts creates series by column or row, but I assumed column
```

Comment: Hello Kieran , i have tried the code , but at the last line of code i got an error like , 'object' does not contain a definition for 'get_Range' . in my excel file the chart data range is now like this =Trend_NCM!$A$2:$AB$7, from above photo you can refer it , i just want to increase the chart from AB column to AC if i updates any data in that column . i hope you got my point .

Comment: You may be using a reference to V14.0.0.0 instead of V12.0.0.0 of excel interop tools. See my updated answer and the commented code.

Comment: use this: series.Values = (Excel.Range)sheet.Range[sheet.Cells[1, 1], sheet.Cells[4, 5]];

Comment: hello @KieranBristow and frankiehf . i have tried with the above code and using V10.0.0.0 , but the answer is still remain same , only columns are updating , but chart is not dragged to the new column .

Comment: Does it still throw an error? I do not have access to V10.0.0.0 and have not used it myself so I cannot test on my end.

Comment: no , its not an error , but the required result is not coming . chart remains same with current range, resulting the graph will be same.

Comment: Are you saving the changes after making them? E.g. running book.Close(true); before exiting?

Comment: yes , like this ,      xlWorkBook.Save();
                xlWorkBook.Close(misValue, misValue, misValue);
                xlApp.Quit();

                // release all the application object from the memory
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(rng);
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);

Comment: What kind of chart are you using?

Comment: I think i'm using column+line type.

Comment: hello @KieranBristow , i tried with following code , i don't know what's theissue , only my data is becoming bold after inserting the data , but chart is remains same . i tried with all possible ways. thanks for your valuable suggestions . if possible let me know the issue , else i will take care of it

Comment: Sorry I was unable to help. Good luck getting it sorted.

Comment: @KieranBristow , Hope you are doing well . I need some suggestions for this,please let me know , i want to get the result .How to use series collection for changing the chart range formula.